# Vscode on ParrotOS : ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Tags: visual-studio-code, parrot-os

I just installed [ParrotOS](https://parrotsec.org/) and installed VSCODE from the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) :

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > 
microsoft.gpg
sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install code
```

But I can't load any extensions. If I open the Developer Tools, I can see the following error :

```
ERR net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED: Error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

How can I authorize vscode to connect ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated:  vscode has been added to the official repo for a long while now  and is installable with the usual:
`apt update && apt dist-upgrade && apt install code`

You always want to use dist-upgrade to keep your packages harmonious.

<strike>You should be able to run it with:

`firejail --noprofile`

**BUT YOU SHOULD NOT ADD REPOS TO PARROTOS**

ParrotOS is a rolling release distribution and you **will** break your system.</strike>

https://community.parrotsec.org/t/apt-add-repository-error/1517/2

It is highly recommended you use a virtual machine for this type of thing (ParrotOS ships with VirtualBox and an appropriate firejail profile for VirtualBox as well).
https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian

Answer (score 0):

When you install VSCode you can see that the last two lines are:

```
Configuring sandbox profiles...
Sandbox profiles updated!
```

From [Parrot 3.9 there is the sandbox feature](https://blog.parrotsec.org/parrot-3-9-release-notes/) using [firejail](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail). This system creates a profile file under **/etc/firejail** for every installation. The file contains rules to protect your application, such as [Networking rules](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/basic-usage/#networking).

As you can see in the documentation:

> –net=none creates a network namespace unconnected to the real network. The sandbox looks like a computer without any network interfaces.

So you have to comment (or delete) in **/etc/firejail/code.profile** the line

```
net none
```

Your VSCode will load the extensions list now! (I had the same problem)

**EDIT:**
Pay attention to updates, because the Firejail profile files are overwritten, as you can see in the profile file:

```
# This file is overwritten after every install/update
```

If you update/upgrade your system for example, check something like this:

```
 Configuration file '/etc/firejail/code.profile'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** code.profile (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

Answer (score 0):

In parrotsec os most applications started from launchers (GUI Menu) do so sandboxed.If you wish to start an application unsandboxed with no restrictions posed just launch them from the terminal like so

```
/usr/bin/<appname>
```